# Docusign Formula field use via SOAP: Formula disappear after sending to the recipient

Tags: apex, integration, formula, docusign

I have a docusign formula field in my template,

- If I generate the envelope direcly with docusign console and send to the recipient, I can see the formula is working fine,
- If I generate the envelope through salesforce and send to the recipient, in this scenario the formula does not work and what I can see is the value in the formula field is missing.

Am I missing anything here while I send the envelope programatically?
Following is the code to prepare the fields to create the docusign tab, (These are the once that I'm passing to the webservice)

```
    public Tab cloneTab(){
        Tab newTab = new Tab();
        newTab.recipientRec = recipientRec;
        newTab.docRec = docRec;
        newTab.tabType = tabType;
        newTab.AnchorTabString = AnchorTabString;
        newTab.ignoreIfNotPresent = ignoreIfNotPresent;
        newTab.tabLabel = tabLabel;
        newTab.valueStr = valueStr;
        newTab.customTabType = customTabType;
        newTab.customTabRequired = customTabRequired;
        newTab.customTabLocked = customTabLocked;
        newTab.customTabWidth = customTabWidth;
        newTab.customTabHeight = customTabHeight;
        newTab.CustomTabDisableAutoSize = CustomTabDisableAutoSize;
        newTab.valueObj = valueObj;
        newTab.formula = formula;
        return newTab;
    }
```

[image: Before send it]

[image: After sending it]